# Value of variable does not change instantly in activity

Tags: android

I am making a edit profile page , in which  i display profile picture of the user the user can edit the profile picture . before clicking submit the i want to save the final updated url of profile picture . The problem is that if i change the profile picture and and instantly click on submit the value of variable storing the url doen not change but if i wait for few seconds it changes is there a way to get the value updated instantly.

```
 **My edit profile class**



public class DocEditProfileInfo extends DocBaseActivity {
  private static final String TAG = 
    private String profilePicUrl;
    public String profilepicUrlComplete;

    ArrayList<String> mImagesString = new ArrayList<>();
    private ProgressBar imageProgressBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

        imageProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        setUpRestAdapter();
        setSalutation();
        setDocPersonalDetails();
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_new);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setDialogForImage();
            }
        });


        docSubmitInfo.setOnClickListener(this);


    }





    private void setDialogForImage() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_select_from_source);
        Button btnCamera = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);

        Button btnDocs = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnDoc);
        btnDocs.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Button btnGallery = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnGallery);
        dialog.show();
        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
// Start the Intent
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Uri mImageCaptureUri;
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            // Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            // Glide.with(this).load(selectedImageUri).fitCenter().into(personImage);
            personImage.setImageBitmap(getRoundedShape(bp));
            //   personImage.setImageBitmap(bp);
            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bp);
            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            File filePath = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
            sendImagesToServerFromCamera(filePath.getPath());


        } else if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      /*      Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult: URI " + selectedImageUri);
            Glide.with(this).load(selectedImageUri).into(personImage);*/

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            personImage.setImageBitmap(getRoundedShape(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString)));
            sendImagesToServerFromCamera(imgDecodableString);


        }
    }

    public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
       *******
    }


    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri tempUri) {
        ********
    }

    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
      *********
    }

    private void sendImagesToServerFromCamera(String path) {
        File imgPath = new File(path);
        Log.e(TAG, "PATH " + path);
        RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"), imgPath);
        //For sending all types of images , presently only jpg allowed
        //  RequestBody fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), imgPath);
        MultipartBody.Part body =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", imgPath.getName(), requestFile);
  /*      MultipartBody.Part body =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", imgPath.getName(), fbody);*/

        Call<ProfilePicture> call = ProfilePicAdapter.sendProfilePic(body);


        call.enqueue(new Callback<ProfilePicture>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ProfilePicture> call, Response<ProfilePicture> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    profilePicUrl = response.body().getUrl();
                    //  profilepicUrlComplete = BASE_URL_FOR_IMAGE + profilePicUrl;
                    //    String profilePicUrl =  BASE_URL_FOR_IMAGE + profilePicUrl;
                    if (response.body().getUrl() != null) {
                        profilePicUrl = response.body().getUrl();
                        String profilePictureUrlComplete = BASE_URL_FOR_IMAGE + profilePicUrl;
                        setProfilePicURL(profilePictureUrlComplete);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "UNSUCCESSFUL RESPONSE " + response.errorBody() + "*" + response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ProfilePicture> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.toString());
            }
        });
    }

 private void setProfilePicURL(String profilePictureUrlComplete) {
    profilepicUrlComplete = profilePictureUrlComplete;
    Log.e(TAG, "setProfilePicURL: " + profilePictureUrlComplete);
}    

    private void setDocPersonalDetails() {
       *********
}



    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isEditProfileValid()) {

                Log.e(TAG, "onClick: PROFILE URL " + profilepicUrlComplete);
                ***docPersonalDetailsUpdate.setProfilePic(profilepicUrlComplete);***
                Call<DoctorProfile> call = docPersonalDetailsUpdateAdapter.docEditPersonalDetails(docPersonalDetailsUpdate);
                if (NetworkUtils.isNetworkConnected(this)) {
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<DoctorProfile>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<DoctorProfile> call, Response<DoctorProfile> response) {

                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                                finish();


                            }
                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<DoctorProfile> call, Throwable t) {

                            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ");
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    SnakBarUtils.networkConnected(this);
                }

            }
```

Comment: To clarify you get the log "setProfilePicURL: <new url>" but then you get the log "onClick: PROFILE URL : <old url>"?

Comment: yes , "setProfilePicURL: <new url> gives new url while on click old url